# Ansible AWX: wrong in Playbook

Tags: ansible, yaml, ansible-awx

Following in yaml of Playbook which I am run from AWX Ansible.

```
---
- hosts: all
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
  - copy: 
      content: "My content" 
      dest: "01.txt"
```

But getting following exception:-

```
Cannot parse as JSON (error: No JSON object could be decoded) or YAML (error: Input type `list` is not a dictionary).
```

Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 2):

`content:` and `dest:` should not be at the same indentation as `copy:`:

```
tasks:
- copy:
    content: hello world
    dest: /etc/passwd
```

Answer (score 2):

Refer the ansible guideline for copy module:

```
- name: Copy using the 'content' for inline data
  copy:
    content: '# This file was moved to /etc/other.conf'
    dest: /etc/mine.conf'
```

** Basically content and dest should not be at the same identation level as copy.